# can't draw tkinter image in function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i'm making a monopoly game, & i am trying to draw image on canvas, but it will only work if not in function:

```
def make_image(root, location, canvas):
photo = PhotoImage(file = root)
canvas.create_image(location["X"],location["Y"], image = photo, anchor = "nw")

class something():
def start(self, controller):
    self.controller = controller
    #photo = PhotoImage(file = "googolopoly.png")
    #self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = photo, anchor = "nw")
    make_image("googolopoly.png", {"X":0,"Y":0}, self.canvas)
    make_text(self.canvas, "MONOPOLY!!!!", {"X":1050,"Y":20})
    make_button(self.main_tk, self.canvas, "roll dice", lambda: self.roll_dice(), {"X":1100, "Y":50}, 100)
    for i in range(controller.player_number):
        self.players.append(make_text(self.canvas, str(i+1), {"X":902+i*10, "Y":946}))
    self.main_tk.mainloop()
```

currently it won't draw a picture, but if i get down the comments it will work (no function)
it also happens after main loop, when i want to draw players

i really need it as a function. what to do? if you need i can put some more code

Comment: you sure you want it on canvas? it would be easier to do on a Label

Comment: Actually I don't know what a lable is. What I wrote is what we were taught at class. If you say there is an easier solution please add an answer. (But I am using canvas for everything else)

Comment: Can you please post another question on how to do that with Labels?
A label is a text element on the window by the way

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Does your program crash? Does it create the wrong image? does it create a blank image? Have you researched this? There are many questions and answers along the lines of "why doesn't my image show up when created in a function?".

Comment: the image is just not shown but the program will continue to work fine @BryanOakley

Comment: @Bryan Oakley As Liam said

Answer (score 3):

You were missing this line of code: `myCanvas.image = photo`.

And even if it would be easier to draw the image on a Label, with this code you can do it on a Canvas with the function `make_image()`:

```
from Tkinter import *


def make_image(filename, location, canvas):
    photo  = PhotoImage(file=filename)
    myCanvas.image = photo
    myCanvas.create_image(0,0, image = photo, anchor = "nw")



root = Tk()

myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
myCanvas.grid()


make_image("image.gif", (5,5,95,95), myCanvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But you say you want to create a variable named photo in the class mycanvas? So it will remake the variable every time I make the photo won't it?

Comment: something like that @AlonKagan

Comment: does it work @AlonKagan?

Comment: Actually I am not  home, but if I call the function a second time won't it delete last picture?

Comment: It will not @AlonKagan

Comment: OK, thanks I will update in an hour

Comment: it did delete them, but i made canvas.photos an array of all photos, and now it works. thanks

Comment: but can i do it without taking so much memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111912/discussion-between-liam-and-alon-kagan).